# How do I translate a system app correctly

Tags: android, localization, translate

I'm trying to localize a system app from an 'unknown' Chinese android device by editing the strings.xml files. What is the correct way to do this?

I only have ADB access and no root.

So how can I change the strings of an installed system app? You can just show me a way to follow like "dump the eMMC and do that" etc.

I've tried to extract the APK, decompile, translate, recompile and install
result: It fails due to signature, ofc.

I've tried to extract the APK, translate as above, remove the system app using ADB, install the new one
result: The app won't install because it's not completely removed from the device somehow.

I've tried to translate, change the package name, recompile and install
result: The app won't open anymore. It just crashes as it is launched.